# Tell SQL Server 2008 R2 to use user name a password to avoid error 18452 using Access 2010 VBA and linked tables

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, vba, linked-tables

I am working with SQL Server 2008 R2 and MS Access 2010.  I have an .accdb with linked tables and use a login and password instead of windows authentication because we have several remote users.  I have no trouble using this login and password using SSMS or my Access .adp project.

I have successfully created the DSN-less connection for my tables using the code from Doug Steele’s site http://www.accessmvp.com/djsteele/DSNLessLinks.html  but I am having trouble with creating the cached connection from MS Office Blogs http://blogs.office.com/2011/04/08/power-tip-improve-the-security-of-database-connections/ .

I continue to get the following error:

```
Connection Failed: SQLState ;28000', Server Error 18452, 
The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot 
be used with Windows authentication.
```

This is at the point where the code tries to pass a test query to SQL:

```
Set rst = dbCurrent.OpenRecordset(strTable, dbOpenSnapshot)
```

And then when I click ok, I get the SQL Server Login screen with `Use trusted connection` checked (which I don't want) and a login ID auto-filled that is not the ID that I supplied via code.

So, number one, why is Access/SQL continually trying to connect using windows authentication when I don’t want it to.  Is there a way to specify NOT to?  `Trusted_Connection = NO` doesn’t seem to work.

Secondly (less importantly, but curious), the login ID is auto-filled but is not what I have for a login in my code.  Why is SQL Server picking up a different login ID?

**Note:**
If I uncheck `Use trusted connection` and fill in the correct login and password (which the VBA code is receiving correctly – I checked using `debug.print` to check my connection string), then the cached connection works.  Therefore I also know my connection string is correct in the code.

I have double checked and my SQL Server is set to “mixed mode” to allow the login and password.  (per post MS SQL Server (2008 R2) Error 18452 with Access 2010)

I do have “Native Client” installed (per post “How do I setup and ADODB connection to SQL Server 2008 inf Microsoft Access 2010)

My code:

```
Dim dbCurrent As DAO.Database
Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Dim strConnection As String

Dim strTable As String

strTable = "one of my linked tables"

strConnection = "ODBC;DRIVER={sql Server};" & _
                "DATABASE=MyDatabase;" & _
                "SERVER=MyServer;"

Set dbCurrent = DBEngine.Workspaces(0).Databases(0)
Set qdf = dbCurrent.CreateQueryDef("")

With qdf
    .Connect = strConnection & _
               "UID=" & strUserName & ";" & _
               "PWD=" & strPassword
    .SQL = "Select Current_User ();"

    Set rst = dbCurrent.OpenRecordset(strTable, dbOpenSnapshot)

End Wit
InitConnect = True
```

Comment: Have a look at the recent answer to another question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25922622/2144390). I'm quite sure that @AlbertD.Kallal can explain it better than I can, but my understanding is that your SQL Server credentials are validated when you first establish the connection and remain in effect for the life of your application. So, you create your links *without* the "Save password" option and have your application startup code make the first connect (which will prompt for UserName and Password). From then on you should be OK. Also, AFAIK `Trusted_Connection=no` *should* work....

Comment: Thanks Mr. Thompson!  The Power Tip that A. D. Kallal is talking about is the one I am working with.  Like they suggest, I do not want to save the password so I don't think I want to use the "MyTableDef.Attributes = DB_AttachSavePwd".  The problem I am running into is in fact getting the SQL Server credentials validated when I establish that first connection.  I want to pass the user name and pswd in my connection string but instead it keeps trying to connect using a trusted connection which produces the error.

Comment: I also looked at this which suggested relinking a table (or all of them via code) - which I tried, but it basically does the same thing I'm trying to avoid for users once I deploy it (which is having to uncheck the "trusted connection" box and enter my UID and Pwd)  I want them to only have to enter it into my log-in form so they should never see the SQL Server login form.   http://bytes.com/topic/access/answers/190474-getting-trusted-connection-log-when-not-wanted

Comment: This code finally worked when I changed the line above "Set rst = dbCurrent.OpenRecordset(strTable, dbOpenSnapshot)" to read "Set rst = qdf.OpenRecordset(dbOpenSnapshot, dbSQLPassThrough)".  This was the original code from http://blogs.office.com/2011/04/08/power-tip-improve-the-security-of-database-connections/ so maybe it was my coder error all along!  BUT I also switched from 2010 to 2013 - then it works, so I wonder if maybe I was using the wrong version of Access for the code they posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things:

First, ensure that your created SQL logon works. Note that you need BOTH a sql logon, and the ALSO a SQL user created for the given database (so don’t confuse the difference between a SQL server logon and that of SQL server user – this is  COMMON confusion)

Use the SQL studio tools and disconnect from the database via your authenticated user and now re-connect via your new SQL logon. In other words be 100% sure that such SQL logons work from SSMS. Then (and ONLY then), attempt connecting from Access. So in SSMS test + try your SQL logon + password to ensure it works and lets you open/use the tables. Consider making the SQL logon a “owner” of the database and THEN create the user of the same name for that table.

I of course assume you set SQL server to mixed mode? And if the user(s) are not logged into your domain, then you could well have issues resolving the server name. (try using \192.0.0.50\sqlExpress or whatever your sql ip address and instance name is).

Next up:

Your “test” logon syntax is incorrect and will ALWAYS return false. Try typing your select string into sql server via SSMA and note how it does not work (that select will never work).

Remove the space and the () that you have.

I would just use:

```
.SQL = "Select Current_User;"
```

So your space + the () does not work and needs to be removed.

Also, I do suggest you include the Network-DBMSSOCN, as this means connect via TCP/IP. You likely are, but this enforces the issue.

Eg:

```
  dbCon = "ODBC;DRIVER="SQL Server;" & _
       "SERVER=" & ServerName & ";" & _
       "DATABASE=" & DataBaseName & ";" & _
       "UID=" & USERid & ";" & _
       "PWD=" & USERpw & ";" & _
       "Network=DBMSSOCN"
```

Once you ensured connecting via SQL logon as opposed to windows authentication works in SSMS, then fix your logon “select” command.

Also note that for the pass-word cache to work as a “general” rule the test logon string you use MUST be the same as the linked string + your uid/password. So the tabledef linked string does not have the uid/password.

Thus if the saved table link has things like "APP" etc, or other not required parts in the connection string, then your TEST logon connection string should have those SAME extra values along with the extra uid/logon. So if your test logon and test connection string is rather “different” then existing saved links, then the cache might have issues matching things up for the right table and server.

The code I use for test logon is:

```
Function TestLogin(strcon As String) As Boolean

  On Error GoTo TestError

  Dim dbs          As DAO.Database
  Dim qdf          As DAO.QueryDef

  Set dbs = CurrentDb()
  Set qdf = dbs.CreateQueryDef("")

   qdf.Connect = strcon

   qdf.ReturnsRecords = False

   'Any VALID SQL statement that runs on server will work below.
    qdf.SQL = "Select Current_User;"
   qdf.Execute

   TestLogin = True

   Exit Function

 TestError:
   TestLogin = False
   Exit Function

End Function
```

And code to create the string is:

```
Public Function dbCon(ServerName As String, _
                     DataBaseName As String, _
                     USERid As String, _
                     USERpw As String, _
                     Optional APP As String = "Office 2010", _
                     Optional WSID As String = "SC", _
                     Optional IntegratedSecurity As Boolean = False) As String

      ' returns a SQL server conneciton string
  If IntegratedSecurity = False Then
     dbCon = "ODBC;DRIVER={" & SQLDRIVER & "};" & _
             "SERVER=" & ServerName & ";" & _
             "DATABASE=" & DataBaseName & ";" & _
             "UID=" & USERid & ";" & _
             "PWD=" & USERpw & ";" & _
             "Network=DBMSSOCN"

  Else
     dbCon = "ODBC;DRIVER=" & SQLDRIVER & ";" & _
             "SERVER=" & ServerName & ";" & _
             "DATABASE=" & DataBaseName & ";" & _
             "APP=" & APP & ";" & _
             "WSID=" & WSID & ";" & _
             "Network=DBMSSOCN" & ";" & _
             "Integrated Security= SSPI"
  End If


End Function
```

And my logon "test" is:

```
Public Sub Logon()

  ' this simply tests + logs in the user to the default database.
  ' once this occurs, then a odbc logon prompt for each linked table
  ' should not occur - this works WHEN the connection string used here
  ' matches the odbc connection string exaclty.

    Dim strcon     As String


   ' con string settings are:

   ' server , DataBaseName, User, Password, [Optional Application name], [Optional work station]
   ' last two optional are for sql performance tracing etc. - not required

   strcon = dbCon("albertkallal-pc\SQLEXPRESS", "MyTestDec222", "test", "test")

   Debug.Print TestLogin(strcon)


End Sub
```

I would run/test the above routines WITHOUT launch any Access forms etc. So just test/use the above code. You need to get your logon working and when the logon works, then the prompt will go away.

Comment: Thank you Mr. Kallal! I have ensured your comments: login & user are valid, I am db owner, never used an authenticated user, SQL is in mixed mode. I fixed the .SQL syntax, added “Network=DBMSSOCN”, and cache matches my linked string. The cached connection works after I click “ok” on the error, uncheck “Use trusted connection” and fill in the correct UID and PSWD on the SQL Server login form. Can I trouble-shoot (so no error pop up) and tell Access to not attempt Windows authentication at all but to use the UID and PSWD without the SQL Server login form popping up? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Assuming you have all above correct, it seems your logon code is failing.  I have used SQL server many times in mixed mode. The issue is not related to SQL “attempting” to use authenticated users, but the simple fact that your logon is failing. The fail is what causes the odbc dialog prompt to display at which THEN YOU have a choice to logon either way (and as you state you can choose sql logon and it works). If your logon routine was working fine, then the odbc dialog would not pop up.  One MUST fix this logon before testing any of the table links. I done a edit + posted the 3 routines I use.

Comment: I am still trying to get this to work.  I am able to connect successfully connect using the method Set dbs = OpenDatabase("",False, False, ConnectionString), but am not able to get it to work when I try to connect via Set qdf = dbs.CreateQueryDef("")  qdf.Connect = ConnectionString.  Same connection string, so any idea why I can't connect via a query def?

Comment: I would open up SSMS and check your sql select command. In fact, try using “select 1 as test” as your sql. Something perhaps is preventing your “test” sql line from working since as you note the opendatabase() seems to work. So I would test/change your SQL test in the query example. The “logon” used by a querydef is a DIFFERENT means to connect and is preferred since it times out much faster.

Comment: Thank you Mr. Kallal!  I finally got this working.  I had to change the line "Set rst = dbCurrent.OpenRecordset(strTable, dbOpenSnapshot)" to read "Set rst = qdf.OpenRecordset(dbOpenSnapshot, dbSQLPassThrough)".  I also switched from using Access 2010 to using 2013.  I'm not sure that made a difference, but I had started by using the above line in 2010 in the begining.  I had changed it somewhere along the way in my efforts to make the code work.  Either way, it is now working.  WooHoo!!